# Calculate time between two points in Leaflet Routing Machine depending on transport type

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet

I am using a Leaflet map with Leaflet Routing Machine to get the distance and travel time between two points:

```
  control.on('routeselected', function (e) {
            var routes = e.route;
            var summary = routes.summary;
            // alert distance and time in km and minutes
            console.log('Total distance is ' + summary.totalDistance / 1000 + ' km and total time is ' + Math.round(summary.totalTime % 3600 / 60) + ' minutes');
        });
```

The only problem in this is that i do not know this time calculate with respect to car, bike or walking. Anyone has any idea about this that how can i get time with respect to car, bike or walking?

Comment: which library you are useing?

Comment: @FalkeDesign leaflet routing machine

Comment: I believe you will need more than a simply route to do this. I mean, you can do an imprecise count by assuming that a person walk at 5km/h, a bike goes up to 15-20 km/h and a car around 80-100 km/h. but if the road is in the mountain you'll get a very bad estimate.

Comment: Or if the street allows only 30 km/h

Comment: So the solution is rough estimation?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the [profile](https://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/api/#-lroutingosrmv1), default is 'driving' :

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/193251

Comment: so i am using Mapbox osrm and the following link helps to define profile. 
https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/routing-profile/